# Group and order CPT by month via ACF datepicker

Tags: wordpress, date, advanced-custom-fields

I'd like to group and order my CPT by month, like so:

**June 2017**

- 13-06 Eventname
- 24-06 Eventname

**July 2017**

- 04-07 Eventname

**August 2017**

- 03-08 Eventname
- 23-08 Eventname

I am using a CPT with a datepicker field ('datum') via ACF. I have the current date displayed, but not filtered by month. What am I doing wrong?

What I have so far:

```
<?php
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'   => 'activiteiten',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_key'    => 'datum',
        'orderby'     => 'meta_value',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    ) );
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :  $the_query->the_post();

    $temp_date = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'datum', true );

    if ( $temp_date != $current_header ) {
        $current_header = $temp_date;
        echo "<div class='sub_category_name_wrapper'><h5>$current_header</h5></div>";
    }

    ?>

    <div class="event_content_wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li>        
                <span><?php the_field('datum'); ?></span>
                <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: Is your month header displayed at all or you get only post entries alone?

Comment: the month header isn't displayed, I don't know how to grab the month header

Comment: The only way header is not displayed at all is when the `$temp_date == $current_header`, since `$current_header` is empty at the start then the `$temp_date` could be empty too - check this path.